# How do I go about setting up SSL for my API and my Web Client in a Azure Cloud Service?

Tags: ssl, dns, azure-web-roles, azure-cloud-services

I have 2 web roles in a cloud service; my API and my Web Client.  Im trying to setup SSL for both.  My question is, do I need two SSL certificates?  Do I need 2 domain names?

The endpoint for my api is my.ip.add.ress.  The endpoint for my webclient is my.ip.add.ress:8080.

Im not sure how to add the dns entrees for this as there is nowhere for me to input the port number (which I have learned is because its out of the scope of the dns system).

What am I not understanding?  This seems to be a pretty standard scenario with Azure Cloud Services (it is set up this way in the example project in this tutorial, for instance http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn735914.aspx) but I can't find anywhere that explains explicitly how to handle this scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you are right about DNS not handling port number. For your case, you can simply use one SSL certificate for both endpoints and make the two endpoints have the same domain name. Based on which port is used by user request, the request will be routed to the correct endpoint (API vs. Web Client). Like you said this is a relative common scenario. There is no need to complicate things.

Let's assume you have one domain www.dm.com pointing to the ip address. To access your Web API, your users need to hit https://www.dm.com, without port number which defaults to 443. To access your web client, your users need to hit https://www.dm.com:8080. If you want users to use default port 443 for both web api and web client, you need to create two cloud services instead of one, then web api on one cloud service and web client on the other cloud service. Billing wise, you will be charged the same as one cloud service.

Are there any reasons you want to make 2 different domains and in turn 2 SSL certificates? If so, it is still possible. Based on your requirements, you may have to add extra logic to block requests from the other domain.

Comment: I guess my question is, how do I make the domain point to the two different endpoints if I can't use the A dns record?  If I point my domain to the ip address without the :8080 at the end, will it not just go to the web api rather than my webclient?